# GPS PPS Signal Duty Cycle?

Tags: clock, gps, timing, alignment

just like the title says, I'm trying to figure out the duty cycle of a GPS's Pulse Per Second Signal.
This post and accompanying answers seem to indicate something like a 10% duty cycle:
[GPS PPS signal corresponds to data time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254216/gps-pps-signal-corresponds-to-data-time)

[image]

Whereas the waveform shown at 2:43 in this youtube video show something like a ~25% duty cycle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GAtL5sFmlQg

Is it variable? Is there a standard? I also crawled wikipedia and some of the documentation links to military standards there, but it was a little dense for me and I didn't see anything really jump out... thank you for your kind and generous help!

Comment: The actual *knowable* technical situation is surveyed at the question you link [GPS PPS signal corresponds to data time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/254216/gps-pps-signal-corresponds-to-data-time) - the key practical information you may be missing is that you should not make a system depend on the duty cycle, **rather you should depend only on the active edge** which appears to be the leading one at least for the receivers mentioned there.